# Designing an Efficient neural network for a Regression data

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

By Following the tutorials on Tensorflow and by reading some basic stuff about neural networks, I have modeled a neural network using python and Tensorflow libraries.

As of now,my ".csv" file data is as follows:

```
AT  V   AP  RH  PE
14.96   41.76   1024.07 73.17   463.26
25.18   62.96   1020.04 59.08   444.37
5.11    39.4    1012.16 92.14   488.56
20.86   57.32   1010.24 76.64   446.48
10.82   37.5    1009.23 96.62   473.9
26.27   59.44   1012.23 58.77   443.67
15.89   43.96   1014.02 75.24   467.35
9.48    44.71   1019.12 66.43   478.42
14.64   45  1021.78 41.25   475.98
.....................................
```

As of now,I have designed my neural network to function for multiple inputs and multiple outputs. In the above data,I am considering first three columns as my inputs and next 2 columns as my outputs.So,once I am training the data,If I pass the inputs 14.64,45,1021.78 ,I want my neural network to predict the output values 41.25 and 475.98.
Here is my current code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 100

# Read data from CSV

df = pd.read_csv("H:\MiniThessis\Sample.csv")


# In[173]:

# Seperating out dependent & independent variable

train_x = df[['AT','V','AP']]
train_y = df[['RH','PE']]
trainx = train_x.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
trainy = train_y.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)

n_input = 3
n_classes = 2
n_hidden_1 = 20
n_hidden_2 = 20
n_samples = len(trainx)

# tf Graph Input
#Inserts a placeholder for a tensor that will be always fed.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Set model weights
W_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]))
W_h2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]))
W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
b_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1]))
b_h2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_2]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))


# In[175]:

# Construct a linear model
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W_h1), b_h1)
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, W_h2), b_h2)
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, W_out) + b_out


# In[176]:

# Mean squared error
#cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out_layer, labels=y))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(out_layer-y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
#cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out_layer, labels=y))
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# In[177]:

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[181]:
initialval = 0
finalval = 100
batchcount = int(n_samples/100)
remainder = n_samples%100
print(remainder)

if remainder!=0:
    batchcount = batchcount +1

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        for batchIdx in range(batchcount):
            if remainder != 0 and batchIdx==batchcount-1:
                finalval = finalval-(100-remainder)
            subtrainx = trainx[initialval:finalval]
            subtrainy = trainy[initialval:finalval]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: subtrainx,y: subtrainy})
            initialval = initialval+100
            finalval = finalval+100

            avg_cost += c/batchcount

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    #print("Optimization Finished!")
    #training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: trainx,y: trainy})
    #print(training_cost)

    best = sess.run([out_layer], feed_dict={x: np.array([[14.96,41.76,1024.07]])})
    print(best)
```

**The architecture of my neural network is as follows:**
1) No. of input nodes(n_inputs) and output(n_classes) nodes are 3 and 2 respectively
2)As of now,I am considering two hidden layers ,each having 20 nodes

**I need help regarding in following points:**

1) How do I select the parameters "training_epoch" ; "learning_rate" ; "batch_size" here,so that I can have a better accuracy?

2)I am still not sure about the architecture of my neural network. How many hidden layers is it recommended to use? and also, the number of nodes in each hidden layer?

3)If suppose,in my data,I want to use first two columns as my inputs and next three columns as outputs,then what are the changes,I can make? Do I also need to change my complete architecture?

4)Also,I am not sure about my cost function.Which one is better to use for better accuracy?

5) Also,please let me know,if I am missing some important parameter,which is worth considering!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions you are asking are quite general, and if a universal answer to those would be discovered, then the data scientists would cease to exist, since the process of machine learning system construction would then be automated.

**1,2,4.** The learning rate and epoch count are correspondingly: "the less the better" and "the more the better". In practice however, you also need your machine to finish education before the heat death of universe sets in.

Usually, you look at the values of the error function that is your network score on the dataset you train it on. At first network is learning from data and score gets better with each epoch. After a while, the network learns all it could from the dataset and score stops improving. After that there's no point of continuing. You may also quit earlier if the error is small enough for your uses.

The learning rate can also be chosen on the basis of the evolution of the error. The higher the rate is, the faster the network will finish learning, but if it is too high, the network can overshoot the optimal value of the parameters an get worse and worse over time. So you need to find a compromise between the speed of learning and the accuracy. It is not uncommon to reduce the learning rate as the epoch counter increases.

You've also used the word "accuracy" but you need to first define what it means in terms of your problem. (It is tightly related with the cost function, actually.)
The problem you've described falls into the class of linear\nonlinear regression (as opposed to logistic regression), for these problems the mean square error (which is used in your code) is customary. Those cross-entropy criteria are more suited for classification problems, usually. If you have some domain expertise  about your data you of course may devise specialized cost functions for your network.

There is no single answer about the best structure of the network. It's complexity depends on the function you are trying to approximate. If the connection between input and output data is linear, then you don't need anything more than a single neuron. 
Generally, the task of deciding on the structure of a network is an optimization problem itself. So, you first set aside some test data with answers, then train your network on the rest of data, then see how well it performs on the test data, which it has not seen before. You test network, you modify it, train it, and test again. Based on the performance of the network on both training and test sets you decide how to alter it next.

**3.** You will need to change the number of inputs and outputs. And you will have to train the network anew.

Also, these and many more basic questions are covered in many courses on the internet, consider taking those. One of such courses can be found [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome).